# rcache type freeradius rlm_krb5

Tags: kerberos, freeradius

I am currently experiencing the problem that my freeradius installation with the kerberos5 module does not like my rcache. It spits this error when authenticating.

```
ERROR: (0) krb5: Error verifying credentials (-1765328174): Generic preauthentication failure
```

According to [Kemptechnologies](https://support.kemptechnologies.com/hc/en-us/articles/203860275-Kerberos-Constrained-Delegation) this error code means the rcache format is not supported.

```
-1765328174
KRB5_RCACHE_BADVNO
Unsupported replay cache format version number
```

I tried to disable rcache by using the information provided by MIT.

http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/basic/rcache_def.html

Setting KRB5RCACHETYPE to none to disable it, setting it to `dfl` and setting the KRB5RCACHEDIR to `/tmp` but freeradius seems to not like any option.

Can anyone tell me how i have to format the rcache so that freeradius is able to read it?

Comment: Wait, why _are_ you creating your own rcache? (And also _how_ are you creating it?) Normally the Kerberos library is supposed to format it, not you.

Comment: Well, it's not like i want to create my own rcache. Freeradius just doesn't like the one from Kerberos itself. With standard config, it spits out the error i posted. And i'm not trying to create one, just format it, so that Freeradius can detect it as rcache correctly. I'm setting environment variables described by MIT. http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/basic/rcache_def.html